# password_hash() when verifying password i am getting bool false

Tags: php

this is my signup page

```
$name=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['name']);
$email=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);
$password=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);
$hashpass=password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$mobile=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['phone']);
$state=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['state']);
$city=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['city']);

$sql=$con->prepare('insert into `user` (`name`,`email`,`password`,`mobile`,`state`,`city`) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)');
$sql->bind_param("ssssss",$name,$email,$hashpass,$mobile,$state,$city);
$sql->execute();
```

this is my login page

```
$email=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['email']);
$password=mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST['password']);   
$pass=password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$sql="select `email`,`name`,`password` from `user` where `email`='$email' LIMIT 1";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
var_dump(password_verify($row['password'],$pass));
```

when verifying my password why i am getting bool(false)

Comment: in your login page, you hash the password and try to verify that. you **don't** verify a hash, you verify the password *with* a hash. see also [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) that tells you exactly this. and please don't escape strings when you use them with parameterised queries or hash functions, it's unneccessary to do both and only introduces a breeding ground for new bugs.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann so shoul i do like this var_dump(password_verify($row['password'],$password))

Comment: have you even **read** the documentation page i have linked to?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann yes got it. Thanks for the help